# Intersection of lists, look for on length

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we are looking for the intersection of two lists, we usually do

```
b1 = set(aList).intersection(aList2)
print(b1)
```

however what if we want to get the intersection of the two lists of words of length 4 only.

for example.

So if

```
aList = ["james", "kobe", "ball"]
```

and

```
aList2 = ["jimmy","james","kobe"]
```

I expect b1 to be = ["kobe"]  because kobe is of length 4 while james is not

Do we need to take out all the words of length 4 from the list first ? or is there a way to check while doing the intersection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) for this:

```
four_letter_intersection = {
    word for word in set(list_a).intersection(list_b) if len(word) == 4
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get common element by **Intersection** method of SET.
2. Use **List Comprehension**  to get only words which length is 4

**Demo**:

```
>>> aList = ["james", "kobe", "ball"]
>>> aList2 = ["jimmy","james","kobe"]
>>> b1 = set(aList).intersection(aList2)
>>> b1
set(['james', 'kobe'])
>>> result = [i for i in b1 if len(i)==4]
>>> result
['kobe']
>>>
```

---

**Pass only words which length is 4 for Intersection operation.**

Create `tmp` list from the `aList` which have only words with length 4.

Demo:

```
>>> aList = ["james", "kobe", "ball"]
>>> aList2 = ["jimmy","james","kobe"]
>>> tmp = [i for i in aList if len(i)==4]
>>> tmp
['kobe', 'ball']
>>> b1 = set(tmp).intersection(aList2)
>>> print b1
set(['kobe'])
>>>
```